# InjectModel error unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm taking a course on NestJS. Unfortunately, the course is outdated and many packages too. Now I’m just writing as in this course, but I got an error when adding the @InjectModel(ReviewModel) decorator

`Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression. Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol'.`

review.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ModelType, DocumentType } from '@typegoose/typegoose/lib/types';
import { Types } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from 'nestjs-typegoose';
import { CreateReviewDto } from './dto/create-review.dto';
import { ReviewModel } from './review.model';

@Injectable()
export class ReviewService {
    constructor(@InjectModel(ReviewModel) private readonly reviewModel: ModelType<ReviewModel>) {}

    async create(dto: CreateReviewDto): Promise<DocumentType<ReviewModel>> {
        return this.reviewModel.create(dto);
    }

    async delete(id: string): Promise<DocumentType<ReviewModel> | null> {
        return this.reviewModel.findByIdAndDelete(id).exec();
    }

    async findByProductId(productId: string): Promise<DocumentType<ReviewModel>[]> {
        return this.reviewModel.find({ productId: new Types.ObjectId(productId) }).exec();
    }
}
```

review.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ReviewController } from './review.controller';
import { ReviewModel } from './review.model';
import { TypegooseModule } from 'nestjs-typegoose';
import { ReviewService } from './review.service';

@Module({
    controllers: [ReviewController],
    imports: [
        TypegooseModule.forFeature([
            {
                typegooseClass: ReviewModel,
                schemaOptions: {
                    collection: 'Review',
                },
            },
        ]),
    ],
    providers: [ReviewService],
})
export class ReviewModule {}
```

review.model.ts

```
import { prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import { Base, TimeStamps } from '@typegoose/typegoose/lib/defaultClasses';
import { Types } from 'mongoose';

export interface ReviewModel extends Base {}
export class ReviewModel extends TimeStamps {
    @prop()
    name: string;

    @prop()
    title: string;

    @prop()
    description: string;

    @prop()
    rating: number;

    @prop()
    productId: Types.ObjectId;
}
```

Tell me please how to fix the error without rolling back packages. The course is old, but I need to learn from current dependencies

I just checked the type of accepted argument values, everything seems to be fine

Comment: `@prop({ type: () => Types.ObjectId });` before `productId: Types.ObjectId;`

Comment: did not help, still error

Comment: Can you add your typescript version and `@nestjs/` package versions? `nest info` should be able to print out the nest packages for you

Comment: [System Information]
OS Version     : Windows 10
NodeJS Version : v18.15.0
NPM Version    : 9.5.0

[Nest CLI]
Nest CLI Version : 10.2.1

[Nest Platform Information]
platform-express version : 10.2.8
schematics version       : 10.0.3
testing version          : 10.2.8
common version           : 10.2.8
core version             : 10.2.8
cli version              : 10.2.1

TypeScript: 5.1.3